# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment -- add as global variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-ggplot

I am running Python v3.8.6. When I run the following code, it works.

```
def plot_timeseries(vars_to_plot, plt_config, plt_type=None):
    if plt_config['ggplot']:
        # Use ggplot style (grey background, white grid lines)
        plt.style.use('ggplot')
    # Use the first object in the list to parse common attributes.
    years = calc_year_span(vars_to_plot[0].start_year, vars_to_plot[0].end_year)
    units = vars_to_plot[0].units
    var_short = vars_to_plot[0].short_name
    var_long = getattr(Variables, var_short)['cesm_long_name']
    # Iterate over the variable objects & plot.
    if plt_type == 'diff':
        # Model config difference plot.
        diff_groups = group_vars_diff(vars_to_plot)
        for idx, (dataset, var_dict) in enumerate(diff_groups.items()):
            # Diff = perturbation - reference
            diff_cube = get_diff(var_dict['pert'], var_dict['ref'])
            plt.plot(years, diff_cube.data, linestyle=PlotStyle.styles[idx],
                     color=PlotStyle.colors[idx], label=dataset)
            if plt_config['write_data']:
                # Write var arrays to csv
                plt_config['config_alias'] = dataset
                save_plot_data(var_short, years, diff_cube.data, plt_config, plt_type='diff')
        default_plt_name = get_default_plot_name(var_short, plt_config, plt_type='diff')
    else:
        # Variable timeseries plot.
        for idx, var_obj in enumerate(vars_to_plot):
            plt.plot(years, var_obj.cube.data, linestyle=PlotStyle.styles[idx],
                     color=PlotStyle.colors[idx], label=var_obj.alias)
            if plt_config['write_data']:
                # Write var arrays to csv
                plt_config['config_alias'] = var_obj.alias
                save_plot_data(var_short, years, var_obj.cube.data, plt_config)
        default_plt_name = get_default_plot_name(var_short, plt_config)
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('{} ({})'.format(var_short, units))
    plt.title(plt_config['title'].format(var_obj.exp_full, var_long))
    plt.tight_layout()
    if 'ggplot' in plt_config and not plt_config['ggplot']:
        # Only call when not using ggplot style, otherwise no grid lines will be visible.
        plt.grid()
    plt.legend()
    # Adjust figure size
    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.set_size_inches(12, 8)
    plt.close()
```

However, when I change one of the function parameters to `plt_type='diff'` and run it, I get this error:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var_obj' referenced before assignment`

The error log points to this line of the code: `plt.title(plt_config['title'].format(var_obj.exp_full, var_long))`

To remedy this error, I tried adding `global var_obj` within the function, but then I get this error: `NameError: name 'var_obj' is not defined`

What am I missing?

Comment: `var_obj` is only defined in the `else` block, and it's a bit iffy to use it outside the `for` loop that actually does define it. What value do you *expect* it to have?

Comment: it is basically out-of-scope, is what it is saying...

Comment: When the line `plt.title(plt_config['title'].format(var_obj.exp_full, var_long))` runs, what do you expect `var_obj`'s value to be? It's only defined in the line `for idx, var_obj in enumerate(vars_to_plot)`, so it only refers to one item from `vars_to_plot`. If that line evens runs, that is, since it's in an `else` block, so `var_obj` may not even be defined at that point. But if it is it'll just have its most recent value, that being the last item in `vars_to_plot`. This just doesn't seem like a design choice, but the result of confusion or a mistake with the logic and/or indentation.

Comment: Did you mean to have all of the part  starting with plt.xlabel('Year") and so on to fall under the for loop? Because you're defining `var_obj` in the for loop and it seems like if that's what you're doing, you wouldn't be using it outside of that context.

Comment: The bug is that you use `var_obj` even if you haven't given it a value. What do you want to happen when `plt_type == "diff"`? You can't do `plt.title(plt_config['title'].format(var_obj.exp_full, var_long))` because you don't have a `var_obj.exp_full`. The fix depends on what you want as a title in the failing case.

Comment: There is a secon bug in there, too. `for idx, var_obj in enumerate(vars_to_plot):` - if there aren't any `vars_to_plot`, you won't get a `var_obj`.

Comment: @chepner `var_obj` is passed from another script. I want the plot title to include one of `var_obj`'s attributes called `exp_full`. Do I encompass the for loop that defines `var_obj` around `plt_type == "diff"`?

Comment: Assigning to the name *anywhere* in the function (even in an unreached block) makes it a local variable that shadows a global.